# Copy a file in a new provisioned general-teams channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-files

I want to copy a file in a new provisioned teams in the general-channel via graph.
For that I need the folder-id of the target-folder(general-folder) but it seems that I could not get the folder-id unless i open manually the files tab in the target-teams

. So the inital creation of the folder is only done after I access it via teams or is there any workaround?

[Before I opend the file tabs in teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn6IH.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1IwF.png)